# CodePipeline force retry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I find that when a pipeline stage fails, I can retry. But if I update the stage I cannot retry. Is there a way to do this without committing an empty change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, if you update the stage of pipeline, it's like the pipeline is a "new" pipeline. So there is no "retry" because there is no "fail". So you can just push the "Release Change" button. Hope this link can help you.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-edit.html